# What are the minimum dimensions for a hand soldered castellated hole?

Tags: pcb, via

I need to design a pcb with castellated holes, and another with the corresponding pads. I need to solder them by hand, and I cannot find any guidelines on how to design castellated holes for proper hand soldering assembly. As of now, I have 1 by 2mm pads with more than 5mm spacing between them [image]

But I would like to make them smaller, something like 1x1mm. is this a viable pad size? Given that the castellated hole needs to be even smaller than this, would the average technician be able to solder these together easily?

Thanks!

Comment: Your holes don't look like castellated holes to me. Shouldn't they be on the edge of the board or form an outline to follow the edge of another board?

Comment: @DKNguyen those are the mounting pads to solder the castellated holes on. the mother pcb is just a little bigger so the pads are close to the edge